# Laravel Query Builder for Time Comparison and Sorting

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have two tables

```
courses [ id, nsu_id, course, section, class_start, class_end ] and 

orders [ id, nsu_id]
```

In **courses** table has multiple course and class_start time.

- I want to **compare** between class_start & current time.
- If class_start time is **greater** than current time then i will
  store first class_start time for individual nsu_id since [nsu_id] has multiple
  class_start time  [*The most important thing*].
- And then **sorting** the class_start time.

> **To solve this problem, this is what I have done to controller.**

```
public function xyz()
{

    $time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('Asia/Dhaka'));
    $now=$time->format('H:i a');
    $courses=Course::join('orders', 'orders.nsu_id', '=', 'courses.nsu_id')
         ->select('orders.*','courses.class_start')
         ->where('class_start', '>', $now)
         ->orderBy('class_start', 'ASC')
         ->get();

    return view('xyz',compact('courses'));
}
```

**And i am getting this kind of result**

[image]

[**Issues:**]

1. Class_start timing is not properly sorted.
2. Same nsu_id has multiple class_start time.

**So, is there any logical way to solve this problem ?**

Comment: you have used with method, why u still use join?

Comment: @TsaiKoga  i have no valid reason. just use it out of curiosity. I edited  my question, check it out. And i will appreciate if you help me to solve those issues.

Comment: do u want the records that class_start  > now. And sort class_start asc?

Comment: @TsaiKoga Exactly. And one more thing, i want first(class_start[0]) class_start time since a nsu_id has multiple class_start time.

Comment: correction: I am expecting class_start[0] means first class_start time for individual nsu_id.

Comment: In fact, you need to tell us what's relationship between courses and orders.

Comment: Relationship between courses and orders are Many to one. Example: Many courses has one order or 1 order has many courses. Hope you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by` order, and select the minimal start time by `MIN`

```php
    $courses = Course::join('orders', 'orders.nsu_id', '=', 'courses.nsu_id')
    ->select('orders.nsu_id', DB::raw('MIN(courses.class_start) AS class_start'))
    ->where('courses.class_start', '>', $now)
    ->groupBy('orders.nsu_id')
    ->get();
```

#### Edit:

Because the `class_start` is an string that time is 12 hour AM or PM format .

You can use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert string to `datetime` and then get the minimal time:

```php
->select('orders.nsu_id', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(MIN(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2020-04-05 ', class_start), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')), '%h:%i %p') AS class_start"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your kind assistance and help. I appreciate your cooperation. I have last question, is it possible to convert class_start time in 24 hours format before join. Since class_start times are in 12 hours format which is not giving me proper sort in ascending order and it's conflict with AM & PM.

Comment: @HassanNajmul r u storing class_start as a string (e.g. VARCHAR)?

Comment: @HassanNajmul I have edit the answer for string type.

Comment: I have a confusion. Usually we use small "h" for 12 hours format. But in your edit answer you use small "h" **[%h:%i %p]** but it's converting class_start time to 24 hours format. can you please explain. one more thing, i use **format('H:i a');** for 24 hours format but it giving me 12 hours format. am i wrong or is there something else that i missed ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HassanNajmul `"h"` for 12 hours for the original data in the `class_start`, so mysql can change it to `datetime`, and find the minimal time. And if you want to use the 12 hours format, you can use `DATE_FORMAT(MIN(....))` to change the minimal `datetime `to 12 hours format.

Comment: **DATE_FORMAT(MIN(class_start),'H:i a') AS class_start**  is this correct format? if so, why i can't get any output.

Comment: @HassanNajmul no, firstly, use `STR_TO_DATE` to get the datetime format, so you can get the minimal time. Secondly use `DATE_FORMAT` to change back to 12 hours format, check my anwser.